# Specifying gpus in keras backend without CUDA_VISIBLE

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I have a problem where I have to include both keras and pytorch frameworks in the same program. The frozen feature extractor is in Keras. When I run the Keras feature extractor in multi gpu mode (4 gpus) it takes all the gpus for its execution leaving no space for the second half (pytorch model) I would like to allocate 2 gpus to keras model and the other gpus to the pytorch model. If I set `cuda.visible_devices='0,1'`, it does not allow pytorch to use the other 3 gpus as well which is a sticky situation. 
Another workaround is to set the keras backend session:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 1} )
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

But here, I want to specify which gpus can be used by the session (by ID). 
The error I am getting is CUDA out of memory error while pushing the data onto the gpu before the second half (pytorch section) because keras has already declared gpu occupancy.

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 204.00 MiB (GPU 2; 10.92 GiB total capacity; 14.54 MiB already allocated; 151.50 MiB free; 9.46 MiB cached)
```

I can specify GPUs with pytorch. I just want to do the same with keras.